# Get task from several assignee / team

Tags: task, asana-api

I need to get a list of tasks for several persons (team members).

I see that in the **API** I can specify `one` *assignee*.

Could I specify **a list of** *assignee* or a **team id** to get task related to several *members* ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a great way to fetch all tasks assigned to a list of people, or all tasks in a team.

What you can do is:

- Multiple Assignees: fetch the tasks for a particular assignee (`/tasks?workspace=workspace_id&assignee=user_id&limit=20`) and repeat for all users in your list
- Tasks in a Team: fetch projects in the team (`/teams/:team/projects?limit=20`), and then for each project, fetch tasks in that project (`/projects/:project/tasks?limit=20`)

Please remember to paginate :)

Comment: understood. I'll choose the first solution ?